# Why is it that moving ownership to a function does not give me mutation rights on that variable?

Tags: rust

sorry for the basic question. My understanding is that there are 3 states of being for a variable in a scope. `owned`, `mutable` and `readable`.

An owner can give a variable to another scope as any of the three. A mutable borrow can give a variable to another scope as either `mutable` or `readable` and a read only borrow can only give a read only borrow to another scope.

```rust
fn write_foo(foo: &mut String) {
  foo.push_str("bar");
  read_foo(foo);
}

fn read_foo(foo: &String) {
  print!("{}.", foo);
}

fn main() {
  let mut foo = String::from("Hello");
  read_foo(&foo);
  write_foo(&mut foo);
}
```

but if I were to add another function that takes ownership of `foo` and does the same things to as `main` originally did - the compiler doesn't like it.

```
fn move_foo(foo: String) {
  read_foo(&foo);
  write_foo(&mut foo);
}

fn main() {
  let mut foo = String::from("Hello");
  move_foo(foo);
}
```

I know I can just give out a mutable borrow, but why can I use `move` in a callback scope but not move a variable into a seperate function?

EDIT oh I had to declare the function as `fn move_foo(mut foo: String) {`

Comment: Heh.. I guess you answered your own question. All the borrowing rules will eventually sink in. It takes a little time though. Borrowing, copying, consuming, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Oh I had to declare the function

```rust
fn move_foo(mut foo: String) {
  read_foo(&foo);
  write_foo(&mut foo);
}

fn main() {
  let foo = String::from("Hello");
  move_foo(foo);
}
```